# Avoid duplication in JavaScript way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to prevent for adding duplicate values.

```
if (this.sQuestions.findIndex((item) => 
    item.question.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase() ===  
        this.quest.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase()) > 0) 
{
  this.isQuestionExist = true;
}
else {
  //save function
}
```

It's working except the `sQuestions[0]` element, Why?.

Comment: Can you make your code any harder to read?  I'm sure you can simplify and make it more readable by splitting your expression over several lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing against `> 0` if the item is not found in the array, the function will return `-1` so it should be compared against `-1`

This will be working.

```
if (this.sQuestions.findIndex((item) => item.question.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase() === this.quest.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
  this.isQuestionExist = true;
}
else {
  //save function
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for this purpose. As the documentation states:

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

Example from the documentation:

```js
const set1 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

console.log(set1.has(1));
// expected output: true

console.log(set1.has(5));
// expected output: true

console.log(set1.has(6));
// expected output: false
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you can try

```
let uniqueQuestions = new Set(this.sQuestions)
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance and clarity reasons you should index your questions in a dedicated structure like a `Map`:

```
function getKey(question)
{
    return question.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()
}

var question1 = {
    ID: 1,
    text: 'What time is it?'
}

var question2 = {
    ID: 2,
    text: 'Where is it?'
}

var question3 = {
    ID: 3,
    text: 'What is it?'
}

var questions = new Map()
questions.set(getKey(question1.text), question1)
questions.set(getKey(question2.text), question2)
questions.set(getKey(question3.text), question3)

var quest = 'Where is it?'
var match = questions.get(getKey(quest))
console.log(match)

quest = 'WTF?'
match = questions.get(getKey(quest))
console.log(match)
```

Result:

```
{ ID: 2, text: 'Where is it?' }
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `some` method to check whether the data is existing in your array:

```
if (!this.sQuestions.some(q => q.question == newQuestion)) 
{
  this.isQuestionExist = true;
}
else {
  //save function
}
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(`arr has 1`, arr.some(s=> s == 1))
console.log(`arr has 10`, arr.some(s=> s == 10))
console.log(`arr has 1`, arr.some(s=> s == 6))
```